# Efficiency comparison of two algorithms: Find the number of negative integers in a row-wise / column-wise sorted matrix

Tags: python, c, arrays, algorithm, performance

Here is the link to the full question: https://youtu.be/5dJSZLmDsxk
Question: Make a function that returns the number of negative integers in a two dimensional array, such that the integers of each row in this array increase in size from index 0 to n, while the integers of each column do the same from top to bottom.
E.g.

```
{{-5, -4, -3, -2},
 {-4, -3, -2, -1},
 {-3, -2, -1,  0},
 {-2, -1,  0,  1}}
```

In the video, CS Dojo presents the following solution:

```
def func(M, n, m):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    j = m - 1
    while j >= 0 and i < n:
        if M[i][j] < 0:
            count += j + 1
            i += 1
        else:
            j -= 1
    return count
```

My questions is: Why/Is the following code not as efficient? (The only difference is that the latter starts from the left, and that it increments `count` multiple times <-- But will these two things make any difference?

```
int rows = 3;
int cols = 4;

int count_neg(const int arrays[rows][cols]) {
    int count = 0;
    int pos = cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= pos; j++) {
            if (arrays[i][j] < 0)
                count++;
            else {
                pos = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pos == 0)
            break; /*offers miniscule efficiency improvement?*/
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please assume that these were both written in the same language.

Comment: Add a `loopCount` variable to both solutions, and increment `loopCount` before the `if`. What's the `loopCount` for each solution?

Comment: @user3386109 For the second program it was 8, and for the first, 6, with the 2D array `{{-5, -4, -3, -2},{-4, -3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. (Hint: I would try a 10x10 array where all the numbers are negative to see the real difference between the algorithms. Even the array in the question would show a bigger difference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the second version scans all the negative numbers matrix, and takes **O(n*m)** time (the whole matrix might be negative), while the first one traces the boundary between the negative and non-negative elements, and takes **O(n+m)** time.

To see how the first one works, consider:  Every iteration will either increment `i` or decrement `j`.  `i` can only be incremented **n-1** times, and `j` can only be decremented **m-1** times.